# Is there a package or way that let's me use characters like ï and à just by typing them?

Tags: characters

So i've come to find it annoying that i have to type every ï as \"{i} same with à and other such characters, isn't there a package which allows me to type it freely or program that changes it automatically, thanks in advantage.

Comment: inputenc exists really already for a very long time. If your file is utf8 encoded add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Comment: Are you looking for inputenc ?